# How to create an ActiveRecord relationship which can belong to a user through either foreign key column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a match model (match i.e. a tennis or ping pong match). It involves 2 players (player1, player2) and I'd like my user.matches to return instances of the user across player1 and player2.

The system I have up is as below, but it seems clunky and unintuitive:

USER MODEL:

```
has_many :matches, :foreign_key => "player1_id"
 has_many :reverse_matches, :foreign_key => "player2_id", :class_name => "Match"
```

MATCH MODEL:

```
belongs_to :player1, :foreign_key => "player1_id", :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :player2, :foreign_key => "player2_id", :class_name => "User"
```

I'm open to suggestions about how I structure the model as well (i.e. if player1/player2 columns are not the way to go).

Just remember each match has to belong to 2 and only 2 players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
# User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_matches, foreign_key: 'player1_id', class_name: 'Match' # if player1_id so he played at home
  has_many :away_matches, foreign_key: 'player2_id', class_name: 'Match' # if player2_id so he played to the other player's place

  def all_matches
    Match.where('player1_id = :user_id OR player2_id = :user_id', user_id: self.id)
  end

# Match model
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_player, foreign_key: 'player1_id', class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :away_player, foreign_key: 'player2_id', class_name: 'User'

  def players
    User.where(id: [self.player1_id, self.player2_id])
  end


# usage
user = User.first
user.all_match # => returns the list of all played matches
user.home_matches # => returns the matches where this user was referenced as player1
user.away_matches # => returns the matches where this user was referenced as player2

match = Match.first
match.players # => returns the two players
match.home_player # => returns the player1
```

Comment: OK cool - so there is no way to make the two columns indistinguishable? At this point I am just curious as I would want the granularity of knowing who is playing away vs who is playing at home.

Comment: Nope, you would need a join table to create the relation Player - Match (sort of a has and belongs to many), but its overkill in your case ;)